# Can "unsafe shutdowns" physically damage an SSD?

Tags: ssd, power, smart

CrystalDiskInfo tells me that my SSD has experienced 400+ "unsafe shutdowns". I am not surprised, since I have had to cut power after OS freezes several times.

I wonder if this can cause damage to my SSD in the long term (it is reported as 100% healthy by CDI for now). Can power loss cause hardware failures in my SSD, or only data corruption?

Comment: I'm having a large count of those too (0x1A), with only 0x40 power cycles. PC has not been power cycled by me more than a hundred times(probably not even 30x as it is a year old work PC). Some people on the web mention it is an driver issue. Disk is 970 EVO, OS is Win10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unsafe shutdowns do not physically damage an SSD.

When you cut power, power stops going into the SSD. There is no power surge, and it is a power surge that would damage a component. All it can do is corrupt data on the SSD, but that is not considered physical damage.

> But why does CrystalDiskInfo tells you this info?

Because this is something you want to know if you are troubleshooting a problem. If you are not aware of any power failures on your part, and S.M.A.R.T. is, then you can see that the disk is somehow having a hardware defect. If you can explain the powerfailures yourself, then you know this is not a hardware defect.

Comment: Is that true even if the SSD is in the middle of a write? I've heard of many SSDs having a large cap inside to hold enough power for an emergency power off, is that mostly for protecting the data rather than the medium?

Comment: @grawity that capasitor is indeed to protect the medium, due to the nature of volatile storage. Because of that, a powerloss will not damage the drive. But a powersurge could.

Comment: So what do I do? I  have Ubuntu 22.04, my laptop is an ASUS TUF DASH F15 and the damn Ubuntu keeps freezing on my everyday, in the middle of my work. I am left staring at the screen waiting for it to resolve itself  so I have to hard reset it each day by presssing the power button to get it to work. Is there a way I can flush the bad write operations or something?

Comment: I just got a SMART warning error, I ran a commmand call smartctl and here is what I got. https://imgur.com/a/qunKRgH